# Media Query Issue

Tags: html, css

I am having the weirdest issue with media queries.  In my desktop browser, they work fine when it is resized.  When I test on my iPhone (5C), the media queries are completely ignored.

**EDIT** 
If I change max-width to something absurd like 3000px, the styles get applied just fine..

The media queries are the last items in my stylesheet, fyi.  Here is the media query specific block:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:930px){
html{ font-size:46.875%; }
.arrowdown, .arrowup{ border-width:20px;}
#about .abouttext{
    width:90%;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height:2.7rem;
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
#quotebox{background-color:green;}
#quotebox h3{ width:65%; }
#quotebox div{ width:40%;}
#contact ul li{
    font-size:1.6rem;
    width:90%;
}
.socialbox img{ opacity:1; }
.socialbox a{ margin: 0 20px;}

.hint:hover:before, .hint:hover:after, .hint:focus:before, .hint:focus:after, [data-hint]:hover:before, [data-hint]:hover:after, [data-hint]:focus:before, [data-hint]:focus:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity:0;
}
.hint:after, [data-hint]:after {
    content: "-";
    width:0;
    height:0;
}   

}
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding: max-device-width to your media query along with this following snippet to the head of your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1 user-scalable=no">
```

So your media queries should look like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 930px), only screen and (max-device-width: 930px){
    html{ font-size:46.875%; }
    .arrowdown, .arrowup{ border-width:20px;}
    #about .abouttext {
            width:90%;
            font-size: 1.8rem;
            line-height:2.7rem;
            padding-bottom:40px;
            }
}
```

Comment: *facepalm*  I _completely_ forgot about the meta tag in my HTML.  Thanks for the help!  As soon as I can, I will mark the answer as correct.

Comment: I know that feeling! Sometimes the easiest solutions slip right past you!